# HighCharts show/hide data points

Tags: jquery, highcharts, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set up a HighCharts reporting on same survey data to be used during a panel discussion. Participants vote on 10 questions using their smart phones and a moderator will be going through the results one-by-one in a discussion (not necessarily sequential).

**Target...**

On click of the "eye" icon in the table (jQuery Flip) I want to show the corresponding data points (3 series) in the chart.

Ideally I load the full set of data into the series, hide all and un-hide based on the array index.

**Tried so far...**

The chart already looks fine but I cannot find a good solution to show results in the chart one by one (especially not in sequence!). I tried already fiddling with the data point opacity but this has no effect on the spline/lines.

Image of the chart and the table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VAw5.jpg

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q1c8rtm7/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Average',
        zIndex: 1,
        data: [[2.5,7.6],[7.5,6.4],[12.5,6.6],[17.5,5.4],[22.5,6.2],[27.5,5.4],[32.5,7.0],[37.5,7.2],[42.5,6.4],[47.5,5.8],[52.5,6.6]]
    },
    {
        name: 'Median',
        zIndex: 1,
        lineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: 'rgba(207, 193, 8, 255)',
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'rgba(207, 193, 8, 255)'
        },
        data: [[2.5,7.0000000000],[7.5,6.0000000000],[12.5,6.0000000000],[17.5,5.0000000000],[22.5,6.0000000000],[27.5,6.0000000000],[32.5,6.0000000000],[37.5,7.0000000000],[42.5,7.0000000000],[47.5,6.0000000000],[52.5,7.0000000000]]
    },
     {
        name: 'Min/Max',
         type: 'arearange',
         lineWidth: 0, 
         fillColor: 'rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.2)',
         lineColor: 'rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.2)',
         zIndex: 0,
         marker: {
            enabled: false,
            fillColor: 'rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.2)'
         },
         data: [[2.5,6.0000000000, 10.0000000000],[7.5,5.0000000000, 8.0000000000],[12.5,6.0000000000, 8.0000000000],[17.5,2.0000000000, 8.0000000000],[22.5,3.0000000000, 9.0000000000],[27.5,2.0000000000, 7.0000000000],[32.5,5.0000000000, 9.0000000000],[37.5,6.0000000000, 10.0000000000],[42.5,3.0000000000, 8.0000000000],[47.5,3.0000000000, 9.0000000000],[52.5,6.0000000000, 7.0000000000]]
    }]
```

Thank you for any idea / hint / feedback!

André

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That behavior is not supported by default and requires some custom solution. For example you can manipulate the series data by `setData` method:

```
var dataSets = [
        [
            [2.5, 7.6],
            [7.5, 6.4],
            [12.5, 6.6],
            [17.5, 5.4]
        ],
        [
            [2.5, 7.0000000000],
            [7.5, 6.0000000000],
            [12.5, 6.0000000000],
            [17.5, 5.0000000000]
        ],
        [
            [2.5, 6.0000000000, 10.0000000000],
            [7.5, 5.0000000000, 8.0000000000],
            [12.5, 6.0000000000, 8.0000000000],
            [17.5, 2.0000000000, 8.0000000000]
        ]
    ],
    selections = [false, false, false, false];


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...});

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle'),
    i = 0;

for (; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var index = this.value,
            actualDataSet = [
                [],
                [],
                []
            ];

        selections[index] = !selections[index];

        dataSets[0].forEach(function(el, i) {
            if (selections[i]) {
                actualDataSet[0].push(el.slice());
                actualDataSet[1].push(dataSets[1][i].slice());
                actualDataSet[2].push(dataSets[2][i].slice());
            }
        });

        chart.series.forEach(function(s, j) {
            s.setData(actualDataSet[j], false);
        });

        chart.redraw();
    });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/40ued16x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: I was not expecting more than a few hints / a direction but you have provided the full solution.

Comment: Hi @AUe, I'm sorry ;) Sometimes it is much easier to write a code than explain the whole algorithm. I am glad I could help!